# modify PHP file to limit user download per month to 5 TIME ONLY

Tags: php, mysql

On my web site, I have a user account home page. Users can create apps (like menus
and functions).

After the user finishes, he can click on a link leading to a page that allows him to download the source code for what he created.

What I need is to limit him from visiting the download page more than 5 times every month. After 5 times he shouldn't be able to download the source code until the next month.

You can see the download.php page that I want to limit here: [download.php](http://pastie.org/3692556)

Comment: Please explain more clearly what kind of link it is and where it leads and what users are downloading and from where.

Comment: Why don't you just count the number of times each user has downloaded a particular script in your database?

Comment: hi chrisw :how can i do this ?

Comment: @AlexAmiryan - fair point usually, although pastie.org is well-established, and thus pretty much safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by storing the files you want to protect outside the web root, and then using `readfile()` to send it to the user via PHP when they try to download (and if your code permits it).

So you'll need to add a database to count the number of downloads for a particular user, and of course a mechanism to detect which user is doing the download. This is usually accomplished using session cookies.

Edit: You'll need a new table that counts the downloads per user, so create that. Also you'll need a table of downloads, so you can display the list to the user, so create that. Then write some code to render that list to the screen wherever you want that information, and then link each one to `my_download.php?file=xxx` where `xxx` is your primary key for that table. When this is accessed, ensure that your user is logged in, check that they've not exceeded their download limit, and if all is good, allow them to download using the above approach.

Comment: I've added some more detail - I've given some broad advice, as of course the actual implementation bit is your job `:)`